# How to set priority of conflicting headers c++

Tags: c++, compilation, header

Imagine you have two something.h in two different directories. You cannot write to those directories and do not have root access.

You have code that does :

```
#include <something.h>
```

How do you specify use the something.h in a specific directory and ignore the other ?

Comment: boom ! increased by 20% !

Answer (score 2):

try using:
`#include "../directory/something.h"`
Note that GCC looks for headers using the [Search Path](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path).
You can also ask GCC to look for header files in specified directories. Use `-iquote dir`, to add the directory `dir` to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files.

Comment: also see this: [Directory Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, list of directories that are eligible for searching of what is considered system includes (using angle brackets in #include), is provided as set of `-I` switches to compiler. Often these include directories are specified in makefiles or project files.

Many (but not necessarily all) compilers will honor order of directories listed as include directories - so you should be able to choose your preference by changing that order in your makefiles. However, in some compilers it may be difficult, as some directories are considered always included (like gcc by default assumes that you have `/usr/include` included).
In other words this is very implementation specific.

If you use not angle brackets, but double quotes, then you can simply specify your desired file directly like `#include "dir/file.h"`.

Comment: One version is in /usr/include/foo/ ... the other is in my home directory. When I specify with `#include "fullpath to home directory header"`, it still choose the /usr/include one

Comment: @madreblu Did you try with the `-I` option also?

Comment: Yes, and even with the -I, it still looks at the  /usr/include/foo/ one

Comment: @madreblu: try using your `#include` as the very first line in your .cpp file. Otherwise, that header maybe pulled by another #include above it

Comment: no change, besides, no statement before it added the  /usr/include/foo/ header to the program.

Comment: you should tell more of what's happening - it is very difficult to guess of what you are seeing. assuming you are using gcc, this is official doc about search order: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: A note about the default directories from the docs linked by mvp: `-I` directories take precedence over them. However, you cannot rearrange the order of the default directories using the `-I` flag. You must either use `-nostdinc` to ignore all defaults and then `-I` them in the order you want, or you can link the desired headers to a non-default directory and use `-I`.